# AWS S3 Java SDK: RequestClientOptions.setReadLimit

Tags: java, scala, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

If we consider this S3 upload code

```
val tm: TransferManager = ???
val putRequest = new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, keyName, inputStream, metaData)
putRequest.setStorageClass(storageClass)
putRequest.getRequestClientOptions.setReadLimit(100000)
tm.upload(putRequest)
```

What is the use of the `setReadLimit` method? The [AWS SDK Javadoc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/RequestClientOptions.html#setReadLimit(int)) contains the following description:

*Sets the optional mark-and-reset read limit used for signing and retry purposes.
See Also:
InputStream.mark(int)*

Is my assumption correct in that it is to provide some kind of "checkpointing", such that if the network fails in the middle of an upload process, the API will (internally) perform a retry from the last "marked" position instead of from the beginning of the file?

Answer (score 7):

The TransferManager does have support for "checkpointing" as you describe, although it's not directly related to the readLimit parameter. S3 allows you to upload large objects in [multiple parts](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/mpuoverview.html), and the TransferManager automatically takes care of doing this for you for uploads over a [certain size](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/transfer/TransferManagerConfiguration.html#getMultipartUploadThreshold()). If the upload of a single part fails, the underlying AmazonS3Client only needs to retry the upload of that individual part. If you pass the TransferManager a `File` instead of an `InputStream`, it can even upload multiple parts of the file in parallel to speed up the transfer.

The readLimit parameter is used when you pass the TransferManager (or the underlying AmazonS3Client) an `InputStream` instead of a `File`. Compared to a File, which you can easily seek around in if you need to retry part of an upload, the InputStream interface is much more restrictive. In order to support retries on InputStream uploads, the AmazonS3Client uses the [mark](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#mark-int-) and [reset](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#reset--) methods of the InputStream interface, `mark`ing the stream at the beginning of each upload and `reset`ing to the mark if it needs to retry.

Notice that the mark method takes a `readlimit` parameter, and is only obligated to "remember" as many bytes from the InputStream as you ask it for in advance. Some InputStreams implement `mark` by allocating a `new byte[readlimit]` to buffer the underlying data in memory so it can be replayed if reset is called, which makes it dangerous to blindly `mark` using the length of the object to be uploaded (which might be several gigabytes). Instead, the AmazonS3Client defaults to calling `mark` with a value of 128KB - if your InputStream cares about the `readlimit`, this means the AmazonS3Client won't be able to retry requests that fail after it has sent more than the first 128KB.

If you're using such an InputStream and would like to dedicate more memory to buffering the uploaded data so the AmazonS3Client can retry on failures further along in the upload (or conversely if you'd like to use a smaller buffer and potentially see more failures), you can tune the value that gets used via `setReadLimit`.